# Writing multiple values to a csv file using Javascript on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to write some data to a csv file. I have 2 variables and I need to write them in 2 columns of a csv file. So far I am able to write only one

```
var data1='something';
var data2='stuff'
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync('C:\\Temp\\results\\output.csv', data1);
```

Here I am able to write the data. I need to write data2 in a different column. Please can someone let me know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just enter the separator

```
    fs.writeFileSync('C:\\Temp\\results\\output.csv', data1+ ',' +data2);
```

Comment: It doesn't work by the way